# Copying data using VLOOKUP error

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having problem with the formula I'm using in Excel. Since I can't add images here, here's a link:

Here's the link to the sheet, where Sheet 1 is the source data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ispzi99u884ic9i/New%20Microsoft%20Excel%20Worksheet%20%282%29%20-%20Copy.xlsx?dl=0

I'm using this formula: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A1:D1000,2,FALSE)

As of now, I can enter value in column A of Sheet 1 and it will return the whole row containing that. The problem is, when I try to enter "Code1", I notice it doesn't return any data. Can someone explain why that happens? I'm an Excel noob...

Comment: Looks like it's returning the row on Sheet 2. If you type Code1 into A5, what do you see on row 5?

Comment: It doesn't return anything but when I try adding a different value, like Code4, it returns the correct row. It's just the first value, Code1, that I'm hacing problem with.

Comment: Does the word Code1 on Sheet1 maybe have a trailing space? Make sure it doesn't. And if you try doing this: =VLOOKUP("Code1",Sheet1!A1:D1000,2,FALSE)...does that work?

Comment: By the way, what I did to copy the formula on the rest is copy the formula from B1 downwards, them copy B1 to then last cell, then drag/copy to columns c to 1.. just thought there might be something wrong with the way I copied it.

Comment: When you drag across, make sure the first argument of the VLOOKUP is column-locked like this: $A2, this ensures that it will always look up A2 as you move across the columns.

Comment: Don't you mean to lock the Sheet1 values with $

`=VLOOKUP("Code1",Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1000,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Hmm. I locked the table array: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1000,2,FALSE), but now I can't seem to copy the formula to rest of the columns? Any right way to copy it?

Comment: I added the link to the file if that helps better. Thanks for all the help! didn't locked the table array as I had problem copying it.. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lock the *table_array* parameter down as an absolute cell range reference with the `$` symbol.

`=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1000,2,FALSE)`

I've also locked down the column portion of the A2 reference so that is will not change if filled right (mentioned above by @Fayyaadh). When you were filling down, the relative `A1:D1000` was changing to A2:D1001, A3:D1002, etc. By the time you got to row 8, this was `Sheet1!A7:D1006` which no longer encompassed your *Code1* *lookup_value*.

If you want to fill right (aka *drag across*), then perhaps this modification may help.

`=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1000,COLUMN(B:B),FALSE)`

This will change to `COLUMN(C:C)`, etc as it is filled right, effectively incrementing the column that you are returning (e.g. *2, 3, 4, etc*).

Comment: Thanks! I got the correct results using this, and changing $D$1000 to $I$1000! Thanks! :)